# How to pass value in select method in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one problem in AngularJS. How to pass list value in html select method
Here is my code,

#### app.js

```js
$scope.subcategory = function() {

  var query = "SELECT unit FROM Length;";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
    if (res.rows.length > 0) {

      var message = "SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(1).unit;
      $scope.list = message;
    }
  });
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<select ng-change="subcategory()" ng-options="x.list for x in subcategory"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function param's to make this work or `$scope`. For example, parsing `subcategory.id` (I don't know if id attributes does exists for you) to subselect categories by categoryId. You should also define a model by using `ng-model`.

#### View

```
<select ng-options="x.list for x in subcategory" 
        ng-model="selectedItem" 
        ng-change="subcategory()">
</select>
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.subcategory = function() {

    //you can also access categoryId with 
    var query = "SELECT unit FROM Length WHERE id = "+ $scope.selectedItem.id+";";

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
        if(res.rows.length > 0) {
            var message = "SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(1).unit ;
            $scope.list=message;
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: So, could you create a plunker. Seems like your problem is something different. `$scope.subcategory()` is triggered fine in my test.

Comment: Your plunker has some error `Uncaught ReferenceError: example is not defined`. Please fix that first.

Comment: @MilanPatel, whats up?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-options="x.list for x in subcategory" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="subcategory()"></select>
```

You can have access to the selected option fron inside the subcategory() function like this:

```
$scope.subcategory= function() {
   //use the selectedItem as you like
   console.log($scope.selectedItem.id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ng-options` you are making use of `subcategory` whereas in your JS, there is no `variable` named with `subcategory` but it's a `method`.
One cannot simply refer the `method`, unless it returns the list.

What you actually need is a `variable`, that contains the object `list`, that can be looped in the `select` to get the drop-downs.

Moreover, on using `ng-change`, you are not passing any `id`. A better way to do, is to bind the `select` with a `ng-model`, on change, you can have a `watch` on this variable.

You should modify your code somewhat like the following:

*HTML:*

```
<select ng-model="someObject.model" ng-options="x.list for x in subcategory"></select>
```

*JS:*

```
$scope.subcategory = ['list:'[{ 'obj1': 'var1' }, { 'obj2': 'var2' }, { 'obj3': 'var3' }]];
```